# Mongoose interface generator with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mongoose

Is it possible to make a generator in TypeScript that will allow autocomplete when using Mongoose?
Made a database constructor with entity map of key-value pairs where the key is the `schemaName` and the value is the `schema` itself. Made an entity function that gets fields and name:

```js
class Database {
  protected entities = new Map<string, unknown>();

  public entity({name, fields} : { name: string, fields: Record<string, unknown> }) {
    this.entities.set(name, fields);
  }

  public generator(entities: Record<string, unknown>) {
    // ....
  }
}
```

How to make the generator so it'll generate interfaces for the models and the models so there will be an ability to make entities:

```js
const db = new Database();

db.entity({ name: 'user', fields: [] })
```

and after that run a generator that will generate models from those entities so at the end there will be ability to use them like:

```js
db.user

// --- OR ---

db.models.user
```

and there will be an auto complete and TypeScript will work well?

Wanted the generator to write interfaces into a separate declarations file and in the class use `Object.defineProperty` to define the properties but I didn't achieve this.